# LINQ select from SQL Server CE: Specified Cast is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, exception, sql-server-ce

Ok first off, Hi every one this is my first post.

Right now to business, I have created an SQLCE database, created the data context and all the mappings and have successfully filled the database with a load of data. So far so good, now if I want to retrieve the data I get a problem.

Code for getting data

```
var codes = (from c in App.BonusDatabase.tbRawData
             select c).ToList();
```

Running that I get Specified cast is not valid. I'm guessing there is a value somewhere it doesn't like, how can I find what the value is?

```
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader.GetFloat(Int32 ordinal)
at Read_RAW(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at BAT.Bonus.BonusRun(Int32 Week) in Bonus.cs:line 36
at BAT.Bonus.BonusRun() in Bonus.cs:line 25
at BAT.winMain.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in winMain.xaml.cs:line 91
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

Edit: Ok as a cheat I copied the SQL create table query into a another program and got it to count how many times I had int, float, etc. The count is as expected. I then repeated this with the LINQ mapping and it has a matching count, so I don't think the mapping is wrong.

Edit 2:
I just modified the above code to just select 1 field rather than everything like so

```
var codes = (from c in App.BonusDatabase.tbRawData
        select c.CODE).ToList();
```

This works fine but if I then change to another field

```
var codes = (from c in App.BonusDatabase.tbRawData
        select c.PPH).ToList();
```

I get the error. So is this the one thats playing up? If so what could be the problem as its declared as float in both SQL database and my mappings

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the mapping between your class and the table has a property mapped to a database field with an incompatible type, e.g. you have an int property mapped to an nvarchar db field.

Comment: hhhhhhmmmmmm this will be annoying to look for, table I'm looking at has just over 100 Columns.

Answer (score 1):

How is tbRawData declared? Maybe one of the field definitions doesn't match the field in the database.

Comment: Would I have not had an error when filling the actual database with data? i.e if it was mapped wrong and I tried putting String into Int field

Comment: Did you fill the database with the same dataclasses or did you fill it with a different tool?

Comment: The same. The data was from a csv file. As a test I just removed all the data from the csv file except the first line/row. I then wiped all the data from the SQLCE database and refilled it with just that one row. Now when I run my code I don't get a problem. I'm guessing the problem is more to do with filling the database.

Comment: It seems that in one of the fields is a value not expected by your data class. You inserted the data with an import from csv, don't you? So there still can be a mismatch between your data class and the data in the table. Compare the fields declared in the data class with the fields in your database.

Comment: I take that back. Closed the program, went back into to run my code and the problem has returned!

Comment: I have doubled checked my mapping against the database and they match. What else could be causing it?

Comment: I just had an idea which, if you agree is valid, might point to the problem but not why is it a problem. I will explain. (see Edit 2 in first post)

Comment: Right after further investigating its something to do with float values. Is there an issue with this type in SQLCE?

Comment: Using floats was the problem. As soon as I switched the database to use real data type and my mappings to use Single it worked.