# Windows Phone 8 existing database InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, windows-phone, sql-server-ce

I am using pre populated database. When the app starts I copy the db from assets to the isostore.
The Entity:

```
[Table(Name = "NAMES")]
public class NameItem: INotifyPropertyChanged,
INotifyPropertyChanging {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    private string _nameString;
    private int _id;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, Name = "_id")]
    public int NameId {
        get {
            return _id;
        }
        set {
            if (value != _id) {
                OnPropertyChanging("NameId");
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NameId");
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = false, Name = "NAME_TEXT")]
    public String NameString {
        get {
            return _nameString;
        }

        set {
            if (_nameString != value) {
                OnPropertyChanging("NameString");
                _nameString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NameString");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here I try to read data from db:

```
using(var db = new MyDataContext("isostore:/Database/ff.sdf")) {
    var allNameItems = db.NameItems.ToArray(); // exception on this line
    try {
        MessageBox.Show(allNameItems[0].NameString);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

With this code I get InvalidCastException, but db.NameItems.Count() works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065207/linq-select-from-sql-server-ce-specified-cast-is-not-valid) and found the problem, my `id` field in db was BigInt and in Entity it was `int`. I changed it to `long` and it worked.